# How to reorganize messy android navigation graph?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

So I use a single nav_graph.xml for the whole app. As the app grow it become messy jumble like shown below, and now it become so laggy to move around. [image]

Is there any trick to untangle this thing without changing the code too much?

Answer (score 2):

I also had this situation and it is normal , but you should refactor as it gets harder to make changes to that navigation graph or better understand your use cases and do it in the first place. Anyway  the solution to that is you make a `nested navigation graph` for every feature of the app (if possible) , for example for profile option make a profile nested navigation graph now all fragment related to profile will go under that navigation graph and the navigation graph will become more manageable another advantage is that you can scope a viewmodel to the nested navigation graph, that means you can share data related to profile via that viewmodel.

As your navigation graph above how can you share data between those fragment , first you can use arguments but those are for limited data types , second you can have a viewmodel which is scoped to your single activity and and all your fragment share that data but that is also a really messy solution and huge impact on memory usage, since all memory used by activity viewmodel will remain consumed as long as the app is running.

So go will nested navigation graph, or if you want to have more activities you can also do that in that case other activities have their own navigation graphs.